# Winforms application : How to save .mdf to Windows %USERPROFILE% folder?

Tags: .net, mdf

I have a Winforms application and I would like to save my database.mdf to %USERPROFILE% folder. Does anyone know what i need to write to the connection string for this to work? Simply using %USERPROFILE% does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx)

```
   String query = "%USERPROFILE%";
   String pathOfUserProfile = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(query);
   Console.WriteLine(pathofUserProfile);
```

You will get the path in string. Now simply create your connection string as usual

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. It works perfectly. Do you know how I can say to my connection string to create a folder inside %USERPROFILE%? It doesn't let me to create a new folder.

Comment: Please tell me about your error. When you try to create a folder which error did you get

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\devone\Documents\xxx\xxx.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.'

Comment: try creating a folder first using System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("YourDirectoryFullPath");